# How i can write a query inside select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

How can I write this query in Ruby on Rails? Query inside a select

```
SELECT id, 
       company_id, 
       (SELECT name 
        FROM   companies 
        WHERE  id = referred_to_id) AS name 
FROM   referrals 
WHERE  company_id = 21
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [newbie manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php) for info on how to write better questions. For instance, you should explain what models you have and what you have already tried.

Comment: You can rewrite that query with a join instead of a subselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@referrals = Referral.select('id, company_id, (SELECT name FROM companies WHERE  id = referred_to_id) AS name').where(company_id: 21)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails you don't really need to worry about writing SQL like this. [`ActiveRecord`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) handles the creation of all your simple SQL commands.

The code below will give you the company name so long as you have set up your relationships correctly in the models.

```
@referral = Referral.find(21)
@referral.company.name
```

See this [tutorial on Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
@referral = Referral.joins(:company).select([:id,:company_id]).where(id: 21).first
```

Then use

```
@referral.id
@referral.company_id
@referral.company.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using activerecord you can achieve that by:

```
referral = Referral.find(21)
referral.company.name
```

But if you really want face those attributes only you can use:

```
record = Referral.where("referrals.company_id = 21").joins("left join companies on referrals.referred_to_id = companies.id").select("referrals.id , referrals.company_id, companies.name as name").first
```

Now you can access that special object's attributes as:

```
record.id
record.company_id
record.name
```